# Meta class of Share Button under FBML doesn't work

Tags: fbml, share

Trying to build a Share button with the customized parameters of Meta Class in FBML, but it doesn't work.

I have put the following codes into the Static FBML tab.

```
<fb:share-button>

<meta name="title" content="My fan page" />

<meta name="description" content="What a great fan page”/>

</fb:share-button>
```

But, it doesn't show the Title and Description in the pop-up window after clicking the Share button.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to place some additional parameters on your page so that facebook can know what information to display. Take a look at [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).  You'll need to place some `og:tags` on your page.  For example :
`<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>`
that `og:tag` defines what image to display in the share popup.  
Having said that, as i answered in [your previous question about FBML](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8473169/will-old-tab-using-static-fbml-tab-be-removed/8473369#8473369), the functionality of FBML is no longer supported by facebook and **it will stop working**. 
 I recommend that you use a different method for implementing the share button. For example you could use [the share button social plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/)